# Xbox One controller is working in Steam but is not working in games

Tags: elementary-os, games, steam

I try to use my Xbox one controller, and it's working in Steam app (the main button on gamepad launch the Big picture and i can serf though its menu and launch any game). But in any game which support gamepad my xbox one is not working, except the main button (the steam big picture is appear when i press this button). What i have to do? 
My OS specification: Elementary OS Loki (Ubuntu 16.04), Kernel 4.8.5. 
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: it is seems that i have found the resolve of my problem. there are two joystick devices in my os: xbox one and A4 teach. The last one it is the wireless mouse. there were conflict between these devices, and it had resolved when i plug off mouse wireless controller from my lap top. After that the xbox one controller works fine!